# Static ip address issue

Tags: networking, network-manager, static-ip, linux-headers, syslinux

I gave a static IP address using following command

```
network:
        version : 2
        renderer: networkd   ethernets:
    enp0s3:
            dhcp4 : false
            addresses : 192.168.3.244/24
            gateway4 : 192.168.3.1/24   nameservers :   addresses : [ 1.1.1.1, 8.8.4.4]*
```

when i run the following command  "sudo netplan apply"

some sort of error poping up , mentioning below

*etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:5:3: Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation:
ethernets:*

Comment: In future, please don't use unrequired bold text - it's not clever, it makes your question difficult to read. If you need to understand how to form a question, please first take the [tour] then read [ask].

Comment: Your YAML does indeed appear to be inconsistent. Are you asking how to fix it?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/netplan` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/netplan/*.yaml file should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses: 192.168.3.244/24
      gateway4: 192.168.3.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.4.4]
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: `reboot` is not needed here if `sudo netplan apply` worked.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm told that for static IPs, a reboot is required. If just an `apply` works then good.

Comment: according to the several hundred times I've done the `apply` bits, it applies the static IP.  The only time it won't apply is if the network is so convoluted that ARP doesn't propagate and the network routes are fubar.  But that's rare in modern networks.

Comment: Hi @heynnema it working fine,  thanks

Comment: @ThomasWard , Thanks man , I  appreciate you help

Comment: @Kevinjohn Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevinjohn Status please...